# InternalError Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `child_process`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, expo, child-process

I am trying to call a function in a python file from a js file, I got this to work through my console, but I am now trying to implement it in a mobile app using expo.

The way I had set this up is, I have the JS file for a certain screen in my app, this then calls a function in a separate JS file, which then calls the function in the python file.

I am using the `child_process` module to talk to python from JS.

And as I said, this was working before I tried to export the JS function to my screen file.

**index.js**

```
export function foo(process, sentence){

   const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
   const process = spawn("python3", ["./python.py", sentence]);

   ...
}
```

**screen.js**

```
*other imports

import { foo } from "./filepath..."

...
```

But when I run `npm start` I get the following error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
While trying to resolve module `child_process` from file `/Users/mee/Documents/GitHub/project/app/screens/screen.js`, the package `/Users/mee/Documents/GitHub/project/node_modules/child_process/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project/node_modules/child_process/app/screens/screen.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work for few reasons

- `child_process` is part of the node standard library, it's not available in other environments like react-native or browser
- even if above was not true, there is no python3 executable on your phone
- `python.py` file from your local directory wouldn't be even uploaded to the phone because bundler is only uploading one big js file with entire js code combined + assets, `python.py` is neither of those.

Only solution that make sense it to rewrite that code to javascript.

Technically it's not impossible, there might be a way to do that, by compiling python interpreter for mobile platform, or using some tool that translates python code into js, but it's not something that you should consider.

Comment: Hi, I have thought of an alternative solution, by hosting my python code on a server, and making calls to it, I have posted another question if you could take a look maybe? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597974/host-python-on-server-and-call-from-react-expo-app