# Host Python on server and call from React Expo App

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, python-requests, expo

I am working on an app that uses machine learning, and recently run into a problem. I found out that Expo and Python do not really work together.

I thought that a solution would be to host and run my machine learning model (Python) on a server, and then make requests from my JS Expo app, and I thought this would also have the hidden bonus of faster processing compared to just on my laptop.

So, can people confirm whether firstly this is possible (to call python code running on a server, from a JS Expo app) and if so, then provide some recommendations as to where I can host this?

This is for a university project, so I am hoping to find something either free or cheap, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand, how are you calling your python code ? Is the python code an API ?

Comment: Hi, I have created a model in Python using tensorflow, and I want to be able to use a server to train it, and then make calls to the server from my JS Expo app

Answer (score 2):

> I thought this would also have the hidden bonus of faster processing compared to just on my laptop.

If you want to do it for free then lowest tier instances on any cloud will have 1 or 2 cores plus 1-2 GB of RAM, it won't be stronger than your local device and it won't have any hardware acceleration, but if you planned to run that on your phone then it might be enough

> So, can people confirm whether firstly this is possible (to call python code running on a server, from a JS Expo app)

Short answer yes, but
The way you formulated this question does suggest that you don't know how this communication would work. You would need to

- send http request from expo app to some endpoint on your server
- implement server code that could accept that request, in your case it's probably best to do that in python(with sth like django or flask)
- in your server code execute tensorflow code
- if tensorflow code executes quickly you can send results in the response if not you will need to have second endpoint to check results

> This is for a university project, so I am hoping to find something either free or cheap, thanks.

for local development you will need to host it locally either way, for university project it should be enough, but if you want to have it on public server you can get free tier or some starting credits on almost any cloud service e.g. digital ocean gives 100$ credit for students

Alternatively you can use tensorflow in react-native app, you just can't do it in python, https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html?m=1